# Are there known problems with >= and <= and the eval function in JS?

Tags: javascript, eval

I am currently writing a JS rules engine which at one point needs to evaluate boolean expressions using the eval() function.

Firstly I construct an equation as such:

```
var equation = "relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue" + " " + relation.operator +
        " " + "relation.value";
```

*relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue* is the value I want to compare.

*relation.operator* is the operator (either "==", "!=", <=, "<", ">", >=").

*relation.value* is the value I want to compare with.

I then simply pass this string to the eval function and it returns true or false as such:

```
return eval(equation);
```

This works absolutely fine (with words and numbers) or all of the operators except for >= and <=. E.g. When evaluating the equation:

```
relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue <= 100
```

It returns true when previousValue = 0,1,10,100 & all negative numbers but false for everything in between.

I would greatly appreciate the help of anyone to either answer my question or to help me find an alternative solution.

Regards,

Augier.

P.S. I don't need a speech on the insecurities of the eval() function. Any value given to relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue is predefined.

*edit*: Here is the full function:

```
function evaluateRelation(relation)
{
console.log("Evaluating relation")
var currentValue;

//if multiple values
if(relation.value.indexOf(";") != -1)
{
    var values = relation.value.split(";");
    for (x in values)
    {

        var equation = "relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue" + " " + relation.operator +
        " " + "values[x]";
        currentValue = eval(equation);
        if (currentValue)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

//if single value
else
{
    //Evaluate the relation and get boolean
    var equation = "relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue" + " " + relation.operator +
        " " + "relation.value";
        console.log("relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue " + relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue);
    console.log(equation);
    return eval(equation);
}
}
```

Answer: Provided by KennyTM below. A string comparison doesn't work. Converting to a numerical was needed.

Comment: *"It returns true when previousValue = 0,1,10,100 & all negative numbers but false for everything in between."* Can you give an example of what you mean by a value "in between"? E.g., a value that results in a `false` where you expect a `true`? (Surely it was obvious that you'd need to include an example failing value?!)

Comment: `eval("7 <= 100"); // true` in Chrome...

Comment: My apologies T.J. One example in mine: eval("9 <= 100"); //false. I am using chrome

Comment: @Augier: You'll have to quote your code, the problem lies elsewhere: http://jsbin.com/uzolis/2

Comment: @Augier: Probably worth mentioning that you've said you're evaluating the equation `relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue <= 100`, but that's not what your quoted code creates. Your quoted code creates `relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue <= relation.value`.

Comment: I guess `relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue` is a string and then `100` is converted to a string and a string comparison is performed.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes you are correct. That is what I pass to the eval function. But in my trace I log the values of relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue and they come out as expected

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Full function is now in my edit.

Comment: @KennyTM: I bet you're right.

Comment: Have made a minified version of your code, it works perfectly as long relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue etc are ints/floats prior to being joined into the equation variable. parseInt or parseFloat perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't show how `relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue` is obtained, but I guess the type of this variable is still a string. In this case, the right hand side will be treated as a string instead. A string comparison matches all characteristics you mentioned:

```
>>> '-213' <= '100'
true
>>> '0' <= '100'
true
>>> '1' <= '100'
true
>>> '2' <= '100'
false
>>> '10' <= '100'
true
>>> '13' <= '100'
false
```

You need to make sure `relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue` is a number. One solution is use the unary + operator in the comparison, e.g.

```
+relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue <= 100
```

This has nothing to do with `eval`. The problem is the overly liberal implicit conversion in Javascript.

---

Edit: By the way, instead of eval, you could use a dictionary of functions instead. This is faster and also safer. See http://jsperf.com/eval-vs-function-map.

```
var fmap = {
    '>=': function(a, b) { return a >= b; },
    ...
};

fmap[relation.operator](+relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue, 
                        +relation.value);
```

Comment: This absolutely works. Thank you for providing a solution so quickly. Kudos

Comment: Ah yes, using the fmap is a much more elegant solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is comparing strings not numbers.

Make sure that `relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue` and `relation.value` are numbers.

`"11"` > `"100"`: Because `11` comes after `100` in alphabetical order.

11 < 100 in numeric order.

Answer (score 0):

```
var relation = {'relatedTrigger':{'previousValue':"7"}, 'operator':'<=', 'value': "100"};

var equation = "parseFloat(relation.relatedTrigger.previousValue)" + " " + relation.operator + 
    " " + "parseFloat(relation.value)"; 

alert(equation + ", " + eval(equation));
```

This is effectively what you end up with and the extra step to ensure numeric value, not strings are passed seems to work.